# CSS in magento getting rid of hover effects on my products

Tags: css, magento

In my magento store when my products is hovered on the background changes color, and there is a shadow effect. When you remove your mouse, it should go back to exactly as it was before. What is causing the background color to remain the different color? It didn't do this on the development site, and now it is.

https://popstops.com/graphic-inserts/stock-graphics

Answer (score 1):

can you try and comment out this portion of your code and see if this disables the hover effect that you currently see.

File name:
skin/frontend/base/default/js/amasty/amquickview/amquickview.js

Code portion:

```
showLen : function(element) {
    if(!element) return false;

    var hover = $(element).select('.amquickview-hover').first();
    if(!hover){
        hover = this.createHover(element);
    }

    if(hover){
        // This is what you need to comment out. 
        /*
        hover.show();
        if(!this.color) {
            this.color = element.getStyle('background-color');
        }
        element.setStyle({
           backgroundColor: '#eee' 
        });
        */
    }
},
```

as to what i see it changes the background permanently we could try and comment it out to see if it disables the issue you currently have.

Comment: Ok so that got rid of the color change, but as you can also see it gets rid of my quickview feature.

Comment: I used some CSS !important tags to define the colors to override the js. now it works how I want it. That probably would have been easier from the start.

Comment: Yeah i really didn't look at any css since it changes the background color on the developer tools automatically. but yah i agree CSS important is an approach you can do. :)

Answer (score 0):

I see a lot of 404 issues on your site when i tried to check over developer tools on chrome. Try and review these issues and resolve these one by one. It might fix the problem you have with the hover. The main reason why there is a hover effect is due to a javascript that is present on the site at the moment. Another thing that is really showing up on developer tools is slick.min.js try and see if you can resolve this before anything else. see screenshot

[image]

Comment: That was left over from a failed other project. all of that has now been removed.

Comment: something is adding an element style to the .item on hover of a different background color, but then it doesn't go away. I have checked my hover effect in CSS and nothing touches the background color there. it is also adding a position:realtive; not that that seems to change anything.

Comment: Yes cause its javascript based, see my next answer :)